# How to build FaceBook "Like Button" that likes a Page message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, fbml

For example:

- I have a FaceBook Page about my website.
- On my website, I display my 3 most recent FaceBook page messages (graph.facebook.com/[pageId]/[more parameters])
- Next to each FaceBook Page message (as they appear on my website) I would like to add a FaceBook Like button. When the like button is clicked, **a "Like" should be given to the FaceBook Page Message.** How can this be done?

Comment: Are you against using an [`fb:like-box`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)? It might be the best option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the permalink of the post as your `url` in an `fb:like` button. The tricky part will be figuring out what the permalink is, since it takes different forms if it's a link, status, or video. For a link or status update, it's this format:

```
http://www.facebook.com/<PAGE_USERNAME>/posts/<POST_ID>
```

Or, if you don't have a username:

```
http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=<POST_ID>&id=<PAGE_ID>
```

You can determine the post ID and page ID by accessing `http://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>/posts` and splitting the `id` string on the `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `POST` to the `/likes` URL of any object that supports likes. No arguments should be specified. You can remove a like by executing a `DELETE` request to the same URL.

> /OBJECT_ID/likes
>   Like the given object
>   (if it has a /likes connection)

So the URL you should `POST` to, is `https://graph.facebook.com/[pageId]/likes`

Read more under Publishing on this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/